# Merge two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a logical problem to solve an issue. I have two dataframes.

Dataframe_one have the following columns:

```
[Id, workflowprofile_A, workflow_profile_B, important_string_info ]
```

Dataframe_two have the following columns:

```
[workflowprofile, option, workflow]
```

My Problem is that workflowprofile from Dataframe_two can be a workflowprofile_A OR and AND a workflow_profile_B from Dataframe_one. How can i get a merged dataframe where the columns would look like these.

dataframe_three:

```
[Id, workflowprofile_A,workflowprofile_fromA, option_fromA, workflow_fromA,important_string_info_fromA  workflow_profile_B, workflowprofile_fromB, option_fromB, workflow_fromB, important_string_info_fromB]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new column by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html), because always one value is `NaN` and then merge by this column:

```
df1['workflowprofile'] = df1['workflowprofile_A'].fillna(df1['workflow_profile_B'])
#alternative
#df1['workflowprofile'] = df1['workflowprofile_A'].combine_first(df1['workflow_profile_B'])

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='workflowprofile')
```

Sample:

```
print (df1)
   Id  workflowprofile_A  workflow_profile_B  important_string_info
0   1                7.0                 NaN                      8
1   2                NaN                 5.0                      1    

print (df2)
   workflowprofile  option  workflow
0                7       0         0
1                5       9         0
2                7       0         0
3                4       1         2

df1['workflowprofile'] = df1['workflowprofile_A'].fillna(df1['workflow_profile_B'])
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='workflowprofile')
print (df3)
   Id  workflowprofile_A  workflow_profile_B  important_string_info  \
0   1                7.0                 NaN                      8   
1   1                7.0                 NaN                      8   
2   2                NaN                 5.0                      1   

  workflowprofile  option  workflow  
0               7       0         0  
1               7       0         0  
2               5       9         0
```

Comment: That helps. Thanks!